# reupload the type=file once uploaded till submit

Tags: javascript

I am making a form where I need to uplaod images where I can change the uploaded image until I submit the form

```js
function previewImage() {
  var thisElement = event.target
  var file = thisElement.files;
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function(event) {
    thisElement.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("src", event.target.result);
  }
  thisElement.style.display = 'none';
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(file[0])
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file1" accept="image/*" onchange="previewImage();">
<img id="display1"><br>
<input type="file" id="file2" accept="image/*" onchange="previewImage();">
<img id="display2"><br>
<input type="file" id="file3" accept="image/*" onchange="previewImage();">
<img id="display3"><br>
<input type="file" id="file4" accept="image/*" onchange="previewImage();">
<img id="display4"><br>
```

I want to change the uploaded file but I can't do so once I uploaded the file.

Comment: Remove `thisElement.style.display = 'none';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this by:

- Wrap each image in a `<label>` for the relevant input
- Update your image loaded event to target the image specifically using `nextElementSibling.querySelector("img")`
- Wrap the `fileReader.readAsDataURL(file[0])` in an `if` to avoid an error when the user cancels file selection.

That way you can click the image to change it after the first time it is set.

```js
function previewImage() {
  var thisElement = event.target
  var file = thisElement.files;
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function(event) {
    thisElement.nextElementSibling.querySelector("img").setAttribute("src", event.target.result);
  }
  thisElement.style.display = 'none';
  if (file.length) {
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file[0])
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file1" accept="image/*" onchange="previewImage();">
<label for="file1"><img id="display1"></label><br>
<input type="file" id="file2" accept="image/*" onchange="previewImage();">
<label for="file2"><img id="display2"></label><br>
<input type="file" id="file3" accept="image/*" onchange="previewImage();">
<label for="file3"><img id="display3"></label><br>
<input type="file" id="file4" accept="image/*" onchange="previewImage();">
<label for="file4"><img id="display4"></label><br>
```